# How can I update the automatically generated entries of the .cabal and stack.yaml files automatically?

Tags: haskell, version-control, cabal, haskell-stack

A good part of stack.yaml and project.cabal are generated automatically by `cabal init` and `stack init`, respectively.

When I edit the source of the project, some of these entries may need to change drastically.

In particular, the dependencies in stack.yaml and project.cabal and the project.cabal entries other-extensions and exposed-modules should be updated automatically.

How do I do this automatically without clobber?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the command you are looking for is not `stack init`, but `stack new`. Generating `stack.yaml` should not be your goal, but instead the focus should be on generating `project.cabal` or `package.yaml` (if you like `hpack`). Reason for this is that the cabal file specificities the actual dependencies as well as all other boilerplate, while `stack init` uses that info from the cabal file in order to figure out a possible resolver and you can't automate this process with just template interpolation alone. At the same time generating `project.cabal` and all other files in a new project has a very nice solution in `stack`.

You can create a repository like this one in your github account (name is important): [stack-templates](https://github.com/lehins/stack-templates/blob/master/lehins.hsfiles) that contains `.hsfiles` that describe which files need to be generated and how. Then you can use it directly with `stack`, for example for the above repo I can do:

```
$ stack new my-new-project github:lehins/lehins-ghc-7
```

There are various options to the `new` command, one of which is supplying custom variables, which can be very handy for what you are trying to achieve.

Again, the caveat is that `stack.yaml` is the only file that is generated by `stack` without using the template, but that is intentional and it's easy to adjust it later.

**Edit**

@leftaroundabout pointed out that the question was about *updating* and not generating the files. The only way I would ever recommend doing such operation is in a declarative way of re-generating file from scratch instead of an imperative approach of mutating the existing file. Not sure about `cabal init`, but with stack it is just as easy as running `stack new` just one more time:

```
$ cd my-new -project
$ stack new --bare --force -p var:newval my-new-project github:lehins/lehins-ghc-7
```

Trick is you either pass new values for existing variables in the template or modify the template itself.

Comment: So, how to use this to **update** the files? That's what the question was about. (IMHO, `cabal init` does a perfectly fine job at first-time initialisation of the `.cabal` file, don't see why you'd use `stack new` for that.)

Comment: Then this doesn't answer the question. At least as I understand it (and might ask myself), “mutating the existing file” was precisely what it's about: keeping the manually-edited, package-specific entries in the file (such as the description) whilst changing those that `cabal init` auto-resolves when run in a fresh project.

Comment: For  “mutating the existing file” we have text editors, and that process should be restricted to them exclusively. If you want to change the target file you always should modify the source template or the logic that used for generation. If anyone tries to do it differently they are just plain wrong.

Comment: Tell that to Go programmers, or anyone using an OO IDE! –Generally speaking I agree with you, but in this case it definitely would make sense to have some automatic way of re-resolving the dependencies. You _could_ argue that dependencies should not be in the `.cabal` file in the first place, but they are there, that's just how it is.